# magnific passing in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am trying to pass in a list of images to get magnific popup to use the images however if I pass them in as their variable it does not work. I can console.log the output of the variable and paste that in place of the variable in the magnific call and it works just fine. Any ideas why passing the variable here does not work?

[Here](http://jsbin.com/sokidazi/1/edit) you can edit it however you must view it [here](http://jsbin.com/sokidazi/1/) to test it.

Again, you can copy the output of the console.log and paste it in place of the variable **compiledList** and it works just does not work as a variable.

Below is the code...

```
$(function(){

var urlList = ["http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg","http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg","http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg"];


var compiledList = ( '{src : \'' + urlList.join('\'}, {src : \'') + '\'}' );


$('a').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.magnificPopup.open({
items: [compiledList],
gallery: {
  enabled: true
},
type: 'image',
callbacks: {
  open: function() {
  console.log(compiledList);
  }
}
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing currently is making a **String** which when `console.log`ed looks like an object, but it's not. Here are 2 easy options.

1. Just make the `urlList` an array of objects by wraping each url with `{src: "URL"}`
2. Use a `for loop` to iterate over `urlList` and make an array of objects. I've added this code below.

http://jsbin.com/sokidazi/2

```
var urlList = ["http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg","http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg","http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140125162709/cartoonfatness/images/c/c0/Futurama.jpg"],
    i = 0,
    l = urlList.length,
    compiledList = [];
for(;i < l;i++){
  compiledList.push({src: urlList[i]});
}


$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.magnificPopup.open({
  items: compiledList,
    gallery: {
      enabled: true
    },
    type: 'image',
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {
      console.log(compiledList);
      }
    }
  });
});
```